# C++ OOP, blank console when outputting vector of object pointers, unsure if populated vector correctly

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a csv file where I'm trying to store the information within a vector of object pointers.

I have a Item class which stores the name and price from the csv file.

```
class Item
    {
    private:
       std::string name;
       float price;
    public:
       std::string getName() { return name; }
       float getPrice() { return price; }
       void setName(std::string newName) { name = newName; }
       void setPrice(float x) { price = x; }
    };
```

I have a function that updates the fields of instances of that object

```
Item* addItem(const std::string& name, float price)
    {
        Item* obj = new Item();
        obj->setName(name);
        obj->setPrice(price);
        items.push_back(obj);
        return obj;
    };
```

Main code:

global vector

```
std::vector<Item*> items;
```

```
int main()
{
    // CSV file:
    //1 Nachos,4.99,
    //2 Buffalo wings,3.99,
    //  ...

    // Open file into data var
    std::ifstream data("menu.csv");
    // Store data in str
    std::string str;
    while (getline(data, str))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(str);
        // values to collect
        std::string name, price;
        getline(iss, name, ',');
        getline(iss, price, ',');
        // push_back to items vector using class function
        addItem(name, std::stof(price));
    }
    data.close();
    // output vector contents
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << items[i]->Item::getName() << items[i]->Item::getPrice() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to output the code, i get a blank console and am not sure whether the problem lies within the population of the vector or with the method of which i am trying to output the contents of the vector. I'm not sure whether it is a scope problem or not...
Does anyone see where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Well, one thing you're doing wrong is storing a vector of pointers. Why are you doing that, instead of simply having a vector of items, `std::vector<Item>`? All this adds is extra complexity, and a whole bunch of potential problems.

Comment: I would if I could however the assignment dictates I must use a vector of object pointers

Comment: Well, the next thing for you to do is use your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and see what it does. This is exactly what a debugger is for. Have you already tried using a debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and see what it does? If so, what did your debugger show? If you haven't already used your debugger, how come? Every C++ developer is required to know how to use a debugger.

Comment: The most obvious issue is that you don't check if the file opened successfully. If the file open fails the vector does not populate, which is what you see. Always check that files open.

Comment: In `items[i]->Item::getName()` `Item::` is unnecessary.

Comment: *I would if I could however the assignment dictates I must use a vector of object pointers* -- Why do they teach the exact opposite of good C++ practice?  It's like whoever teaches this way is invested in programmers being turned down by prospective employers.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check for:

1. Check if the file has opened correctly. Use the is_open() function like data.is_open();
2. Don't use Item* in vector, just use Item.
3. In the function addItem, you are returning an object pointer and never assigning to any pointer in main. There is no need to return anything from that function. You are adding the object to the vector in the function itself.